# OSGI Integration testing, Pax Exam probe executing tests before container bundles start

Tags: osgi, integration-testing, apache-karaf, pax-exam

I'm currently trying to write an OSGI integration tests using PAX-EXAM+KARAF and faced a problem that pax exam trying to execute test methods before dependent bundles are actually started/initialized in container. What's strange, sometimes test succeeds, and in that case all bundles/contexts are started and logged, but the majority of times it does not. Delays in methods won't help:( Anyone could help with this issue?

I'm using 
PAX-EXAM 2.6.0, 
org.apache.karaf.tooling.exam.container 2.3.0,
apache-karaf 2.3.0.

Code:

```
@Inject
BundleContext bundleContext;

@Inject
    EntityManagerFactoryService entityManagerFactoryService;//Service exposed trough OSGI

    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    @Before
    public void init() throws InterruptedException {
        entityManager = entityManagerFactoryService.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
    }

@Configuration
    public static Option[] configuration() throws Exception {

    return new Option[] {
            karafDistributionConfiguration().frameworkUrl(maven().groupId("org.apache.karaf").artifactId("apache-karaf").type("zip").versionAsInProject())
                    .karafVersion("2.3.0").name("Apache Karaf"),                
mavenBundle("com.google.guava", "guava", "13.0.1").startLevel(30),
mavenBundle("com.mysql.jdbc", "com.springsource.com.mysql.jdbc", "5.1.6").startLevel(30),
                mavenBundle("javax.persistence", "com.springsource.javax.persistence", "2.0.0").startLevel(30),
                mavenBundle("org.apache.commons", "com.springsource.org.apache.commons.lang", "2.6.0").startLevel(30),

...the rest of bundles  

junitBundles(), };
```

Test method:

```
@Test
    public void contextNotNull() {
        Assert.assertNotNull(entityManagerFactoryService);
    }
```

The log:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.startjg.crp.core.dao.service.EntityManagerFactoryService not found by PAXEXAM-PROBE-749fa717-8bdc-4d9a-9803-bdaf6d4edac0 [144]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1460)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:72)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1843)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Full log:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/v12r15sbmtu9svp/log.txt

Also tried with no luck:

```
protected <T> Object getService(Class<T> serviceClass) {
    int maxCount = 5;
    int delay = 5000;
    for (int i = 0; i <= maxCount; i++) {
        if (bundleContext.getServiceReference(serviceClass) != null) {
            ServiceReference<T> serviceReference = bundleContext.getServiceReference(serviceClass);
            return bundleContext.getService(serviceReference);
        } else {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(delay);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Before
public void init() throws InterruptedException {
    EntityManagerFactoryService emfs = (EntityManagerFactoryService) getService(EntityManagerFactoryService.class);
    entityManager = entityManagerFactoryService.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your EntityManager is working and available as Service?
You are most probably missing some dependencies, that's why your bundle containing the service isn't fully started.

Comment: The point was, if using mavenBundle() to install bundles into Karaf, there is no guarantee that bundles will install in desired order. That caused an errors. As a workaround i've used deprecated pax exam method scanFeatures().

Comment: for pax-exam-karaf which uses 2.6 of Pax-Exam it's still the way to work. For Pax-Exam 3.0 there is a issue of resurrecting the scanFeatures configuration

Comment: Yeah, i saw that scanFeatures is back in 3.0, but i didn't manage to get it working with karaf 2.3.0.

Comment: For Pax-Exam 3.0 it's not working at all you need to use 2.6 of Pax-Exam if you test Karaf and use scanFeatures. The Pax-Exam-Karaf provided by the Karaf team right now, is still based on the 2.x line of Pax-Exam.

Answer (score 0):

The current pax exam 3.3.0 now fully supports karaf as a container. The former karaf exam code now fully moved to pax exam.